# ElasticSearch mapping for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I am using dynamic template as follows, Here I am applying n-gram analyzer to all the "String" fields.
However to improve efficiency I would like to apply n-gram only on specific fields only and not on all String fields.

```
{
        "template": "*",
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "ngram_filter": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 25
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "case_insensitive": {
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "ngram_filter",
                            "lowercase"
                        ]
                    },
                    "search_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "my_type": {
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "strings": {
                            "match_mapping_type": "string",
                            "mapping": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                },
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive",
                                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a payload like this:

```
{
   "userId":"abc123-pqr180-xyz124-njd212",
   "email" : "someuser@test.com",
   "name"  : "somename",
   .
   .
   20 more fields
}
```

Now I want to apply n-gram only for "email" and "userid".
How can we do this ?

Comment: Is it conceivable for you to rename the `email` and `name` fields?

Comment: Thanks for reply Val ! , No, I can't rename those fields. In worst case scenario I am ok to specify mapping for each field i.e no dynamic mapping

Comment: The thing is you can use another parameter called `match` in which you can give a name pattern to which the template should be applied, but it doesn't take an array and `email` and `name` have no prefix/suffix in common.

Comment: ok .., can we statically define mapping for each field ?

Comment: of course, simply drop your `dynamic_templates` and use the proper mapping for each of your fields. Another way to do this is to duplicate the dynamic template for the two fields `email` and `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot rename the fields I suggest the following solution, i.e. to duplicate the dynamic template for the `name` and `email` fields.

```
{
        "template": "*",
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "ngram_filter": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 25
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "case_insensitive": {
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "ngram_filter",
                            "lowercase"
                        ]
                    },
                    "search_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "my_type": {
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "names": {
                            "match_mapping_type": "string",
                            "match": "name",
                            "mapping": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                },
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive",
                                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "emails": {
                            "match_mapping_type": "string",
                            "match": "email",
                            "mapping": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                },
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive",
                                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Val ! That helps